# Is there a way to use django-inplaceedit to do in-place editing of a column in django-tables2 TemplateColumn?

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-tables2, django-inplaceedit

I tried to make a state_template.html with

```
{% load inplace_edit %}
{% block extra_header %}
    {% inplace_static %}
{% endblock %}
{% inplace_edit "action.action_state" %}
```

And tables.py has:

```
action_state = tables.TemplateColumn(template_name='django_tables2/state_template.html', verbose_name="State")
```

But since `action` is never being passed to the template, it is giving an error. 
Does anyone have any ideas on how to make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very nice question :-)

I think if you update your template (state_template.html), with this should works:

```
{% load inplace_edit %}

{% block extra_header %}
    {% inplace_static %}
{% endblock %}

{% inplace_edit "record.action_state" %}
```

And this is a recomendation, You should move to the template of the view that renderthe table, but this is only to efficiency:

```
{% block extra_header %}
    {% inplace_static %}
{% endblock %}
```